# Multiple images as entrypoints for GitLab-ci configuration file

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, packer

I am writing a gitlab-ci.yml file to build images using packer and thereafter deploy them with terraform. Since I am new to gitlab, I thought it is possible to reference both Terraform and Packer images like so:

```
image:
 name: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-build-images:terraform
 entrypoint:
   - '/usr/bin/env'
   - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

image:
  name: hashicorp/packer
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
```

Comment: That's not possible. Do you need terraform AND packer in the same job ? Otherwise, you can have an `image` per job.

Comment: @NicolasPepinster do you have a reference to how I can break the process into two jobs haven't found any yet.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, I never used packer and terraform together. On docker hub, there is [images](https://hub.docker.com/r/bryandollery/terraform-packer-aws-alpine) with terraform and packer, I think you can use this one globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one "default" image that is applied to every step in the pipeline, but you can specify an image to use for each job, or just the jobs that are different from the default.

From the GitLab CI documentation here (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-and-services-from-gitlab-ciyml), you can specify a default for all steps to use:

```
default:
  image: ruby:2.6

  services:
    - postgres:11.7

  before_script:
    - bundle install

test:
  script:
    - bundle exec rake spec
```

as well as have some steps differ from the default:

```
default:
  image: ruby:2.6

  services:
    - postgres:11.7

  before_script:
    - bundle install

test: # this uses the default image
  script:
    - bundle exec rake spec

db_setup: # this uses a specific image that is different from the default
  image: mysql:8
  script:
    - mysql -h my_datbase.example.com -u root -ppassword -e "create database my_database"
```